# How to make `paste` command stop on shortest file

Tags: command-line, paste

I have two files:

**a.txt**

```
1
2
3
```

**b.txt**

```
foo
bar
baz
qux
```

Running `paste a.txt b.txt` gives

```
1 foo 
2 bar 
3 baz 
 qux
```

However I want to stop when the shortest file ends (that is, I want to print only complete rows, otherwise a later program down the pipeline will think `qux` is the first field and the second is empty, when really it's the only way around). How can I do this?

Comment: Will this `paste  a.txt b.txt | sed -r '/^\s/d'` help

Comment: what if the 2nd file `b.txt` would contain a line with 2 or more words like `some foo` ?

Answer (score 3):

Same idea as the other answers--paste all lines then select complete lines--but with `awk`:

```
paste a.txt b.txt | awk NF==2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed` command can delete the line that's missing a starting number:

```
paste  a.txt b.txt | sed '/^\s/d'
```

Result:

```
1       foo
2       bar
3       bax
```

Comment: This is no good for the general case. What if a.txt has words instead of numbers? What if I run paste b.txt a.txt?

Comment: If that were stated initially then I would consider other options!

Answer (score 0):

Count lines and `head` the files?

Needs a shell with Process Substitution (`<(…)`) (using bash):

```
$ a=$(wc -l <a.txt)
$ b=$(wc -l <b.txt)
$ if [ "$a" -lt "$b" ]; then min=$a; else min=$b; fi
$ paste <( head '-'"$min" <a.txt ) <(head '-'"$min" <b.txt)
1       foo
2       bar
3       bax
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `paste` does not have any builtin option to skip pasting if lines of files are not equal and since the rest solutions are fragile if your files contain more than one field, i would propose to use awk:

```
$ cat file1
line 1
line 2
line 3

$ cat file2
foo line 1
foo line 2
foo line 3
foo line 4

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;maxfnr=FNR;next}FNR<=maxfnr{print a[FNR],$0}'  file1 file2
line 1 foo line 1
line 2 foo line 2
line 3 foo line 3
```

Same awk solution will work even if file2 is shorter than file1, so this seems to be a global solution not affected by the number of fields in each file nor by which file is shorter:

```
$ cat file1
line 1
line 2
line 3

$ cat file2
foo line 1
foo line 2

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;maxfnr=FNR;next}FNR<=maxfnr{print a[FNR],$0}'  file1 file2
line 1 foo line 1
line 2 foo line 2
```

Comment: why not add some minimal explanation of the awk script

Answer (score 0):

We can use this command which should run in most POSIX `sh` (i.e. no bashisms)

```bash
paste a.txt b.txt | head -n $( { wc -l <a.txt; wc -l b.txt; } | sort -n | head -n 1 )
```

as it will pipe the output of `paste` into a `head -n <lines>` that only lets the number of lines throught of the file with fewer lines.

This is a commented version:

```bash
# We let `paste` do its job normally, with output send into a pipe...
paste a.txt b.txt |
  # ...to `head`, which will stop said output after `-n` lines...  
  head -n $( 
   # ...that are determined by the `wc` counted line lengths `-l` ...
   { 
     wc -l <a.txt # ...of file a.txt...
     wc -l <b.txt # ...and file b.txt ...
   } | 
     # ... being piped to be `sort`ed numerically ascendet list...
     sort -n | 
     # ... where the lower line count being the first line (i.e. "3)
     head -n 1 
  )
```

with

```bash
cat >a.txt << 'EOF'
1
2
3
EOF
# and
cat >b.txt << 'EOF'
foo
bar
baz
qux
EOF
# running... 
paste a.txt b.txt | head -n $( { wc -l <a.txt; wc -l b.txt; } | sort -n | head -n 1 )
```

...yielding desired output

```
1       foo
2       bar
3       bax
```

note that in most setups there shoud be a `SIGPIPE` singal happining that as stated [`man pipe(7)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) should :

> If all file descriptors
> referring to the read end of a pipe have been closed, then a
> write(2) will cause a SIGPIPE signal to be generated for the
> calling process.

meaning that in cases where `paste` hadles very large amount of data not much compational effort is wasted....